# Is there any sort of license or terms of service associated with developing VSTO add-ins

Tags: excel, vsto

We are deploying a VSTO Microsoft Office Add-in to Microsoft Excel within our organization.  This application was developed in-house using a licensed copy of Visual Studio Professional. I have not had any success in finding any Terms of Use associated with VSTO office-addins / the VSTO development framework.  We want to make sure we are not going to get in trouble with legal when deploying this internal app.  Are these Terms of Use clearly spelled out somewhere for VSTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO is a part of Visual Studio. There is no separate license or terms of use.